# Jscroll immediately loading all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make Jscroll infinitely scroll a div of images, but I'm finding that it immediately loads all the pages it can as soon as it's triggered. On Opera, Chrome and Firefox this means it loads thousands of pages in the space of a few seconds, crashing the browser. On Microsoft Edge this means it loads pages any time the user is scrolling either up or down.

This is my html markup for the div in question;

```
<div id="images-wall">
<div class="home-thumb col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4 no-padding"><a href="/image/22" target="_blank"><picture><img class="home-img" src="//thumb.example.com/webp/22.webp" title="Image Name"></picture></a></div>
<nav id="#next"><a href="/more/home/2016-02-12+17:36:45"></a></nav></div>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript I'm using to call jscroll;

```
function reLayout(){
    console.log("Loaded new images.");
}


$('#images-wall').jscroll({
    debug: true,
    padding: 0,
    callback: reLayout,
    loadingHtml: 'LOADING MORE'
});
```

And this is the debugging output put in the console by Jscroll;

```
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
js.js:15376 jScroll: -3082 from bottom. Loading next request...
js.js:15376 Object
```

This is similar to the markup I've used previously on a project to implement jscroll, what have I done wrong here?

EDIT:

I made a minimal example with just this HTML code;

```
<script src="/static/js2.js"></script>
<div id="images-wall">
<a href="/image/22/" target="_blank">
<img class="home-img" src="//thumb.example.com/webp/22.webp" title="Title of the image.">
</a>
<a href="/more/home/2016-02-12+17:36:45"></a>
</div>
```

And the Javascript code that can found [here](http://pastebin.com/8Pphu1mq) and the issue still happens.

Comment: The code you posted seems fine and has nothing to do with loading all the pages. May be you missed out to post other part of code where the might be

Comment: I was sure the markup was fine too, so I made a new Javascript file with just Jquery 2.1.4 (the version I've used on a previous project with Jscroll in case it was an issue with the Jquery version) and Jscroll in it, and the issue still occurred. See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had your exact same problem.. I think.

jscroll will trigger a call when

> The distance from the bottom of the scrollable content at which to trigger the loading of the next set of content. This only applies when autoTrigger is set to true.

Your `padding` is 0. Think about how many actions a cpu can do in a second, then think about what's going to happen the moment a user scrolls to the bottom. The javascript will shoot off requests to the server like BAM BAM BAM BAM. That's why all of your images are coming in at once.

My solution was a boolean variable named `isPaging`. You'll need to set it to `true` when the ajax request is sent, and `false` in the response callback. In the ajax request (You may have to override/modify a jscroll function), you check if `isPaging==true`. If it is, just return so the request isn't sent again.

This way the automatic loading will only occur once. Once the response is received, the container will fill up with content and it's scrollbar will move up. The user can then scroll down to the bottom again, and etc.

EDIT: Found the problem, sort of. Jscroll seems to break when the jscroll container relies on the window to scroll, and not it's own scroll bar. Thus the jscroll calculations for scroll position get all messed up. I still don't know the root cause but i do plan on filing an issue with the creator. ( edit: I see you've already filed an issue, i'll add to it then.)

Add this to your mega file link and it solves the issue.

```
<style>
#images-wall{
height:100%;
}
</style>
```

Also you have an extra closing div tag at the very end.

Comment: Hi Eric,
0 padding should mean the user has to actually hit into the end of the screen before the jscroll will trigger and load just one more page, but in my case it's triggering infinitely with no regards for where the user has scrolled to at all. Jscroll is not loading more than one new page at once, it's just loading new ones one after the other recursively as it always thinks the user has scrolled beyond the end of the div it's bound to.

Comment: I see. Could you replicate the problem with a jsFiddle? It has something to do with the html and the way jscroll is calculating heights. In the debug, jscroll thinks `$inner.outerHeight() - iTotalHeight = -3082`, when it should be some positive number.

Comment: The code works exactly as it should (no recursive loading) inside JSfiddle, here https://jsfiddle.net/h8xd4nhv/2/ but if I copy and paste that code exactly and update the URL to point back to the html file I put the html in, it does the recursive loading again.

Comment: Here's a mega link to a file containing both the javascipt and html. On my system, when I open it, the page recursively loads and crashes (note it won't open in this case on Chrome, while Firefox will run it). https://mega.nz/#!w8tHWLKL!XUSYOfeeN7LTRg-S0PRXrbjx9gjeE0BI57o88rp55R0

Comment: EDIT: I just realised what you meant by edit. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that jScroll doesn't appear to be compatible with Masonry. I was trying to use them together and Masonry appeared to be taking over the div's height attribute, leading to jScroll being unable to determine how much was left of the div. Even the solution in the accepted answer did nothing to solve this. Seek another infinite scroll solution.